# Creating an instance of variable with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to create an instance of type t with reflection, that is

```
Type t = typeof(string);
string s = (t)Activator.CreateInstance(t); // this fails because of convertion
string s = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as t // also fails
```

Is there a way to perform such a convertion?
Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you know the compile-time type of the variable then why not construct the object normally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You have to convert to `string`, not to `t`. You may want a generic method, alternatively:

```
public T GetInstance<T>()
{
    Type t = typeof(T);
    T s = (T)Activator.CreateIstance(t);
    return s;
}
```

As things stand you are attempting to cast an object that is actually an instance of `System.String` to type `System.Type`...

Comment: You could just add a `where T : new()` contstraint on the method and the body would then be a single line: `return new T();`

Comment: Very true, and would be safer as types not implementing a paramaterless constructor could be picked up at compile time.

Comment: If I recall correctly there is a generic overload as well, so you should be able to do Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string s = (string)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Activator.CreateInstance returns an instance boxed in an object so it must be cast to the correct type before you can use it.

In your example t is a Type object variable and not a type reference. You must either specify the type directly as in my example or you can use generics.